# Arcpy TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment, field was defined as FLOAT

Tags: python, tuples, arcgis, arcpy

I'm working on an Arcpy script which prioritizes sewers for repair.  The section I'm having issues with right now is looking to identify sewers within 50' of an interstate.  Several similar code sections have been run by this point in the script and those did not experience issues.
I don't understand what the issue is here.  I inherited this script from someone else, so I don't really undestand how the other code sections worked out (even though they are also defined as FLOAT fields, which should be immutable.)
     Street Location - Important to note, must have "streets" files in listed folder below.  Select all major streets and then the intersection of sewers within the specified buffer limits.
The error returns for `row[1] = 5` , which is when it starts to try to modify the new `WithinInterstates`
Any advice is appreciated.  Thanks!

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("C:/Python27/Shapefiles/Streets.shp", "Streets_fc")
streets = "Streets_fc"
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(streets, "NEW_SELECTION", "(\"CFCC\" = 'A15') OR (\"CFCC\" = 'A63')")
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(streets, "Streets_Interstates", "50 Feet", "FULL", "ROUND", "ALL", "")
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("ruleset4nonfc", "INTERSECT", "Streets_Interstates", "", "NEW_SELECTION")
fieldname = arcpy.ValidateFieldName("WithinInterstates")
arcpy.AddField_management("ruleset4nonfc", fieldname, "FLOAT")
cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("ruleset4nonfc", ["ssGravity_Main_fullcctv_ASSET_ID", "WithinInterstates"])
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor ("ruleset4nonfc", ["ssGravity_Main_fullcctv_ASSET_ID", "WithinInterstates"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] > 0:
        row[1] = 5
        elif row[0] <= 0:
        row[1] = " "
        else:
        pass
del cursor
```

Earlier sections of the code shown below work perfectly and fill out the database as intended:

```
# Flood Plain - Important to note, must have "s_fld_haz_ar" files in listed folder below.  Select all flood area sewers and then the interesection of sewers within these area limits.
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("C:/Python27/Shapefiles/s_fld_haz_ar.shp", "floodplain_limits_fc")
floodplain = "floodplain_limits_fc"
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(floodplain, "NEW_SELECTION", "NOT (\"FLD_ZONE\" = 'X')")
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("ruleset4nonfc", "INTERSECT", floodplain)
fieldname = arcpy.ValidateFieldName("InFloodplain")
arcpy.AddField_management("ruleset4nonfc", fieldname, "FLOAT")
cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("ruleset4nonfc", ["ssGravity_Main_fullcctv_ASSET_ID", "InFloodplain"])
for row in cursor:
    if row[0] > 0:
        row[1] = 3
    else:
        row[1] = 1
    cursor.updateRow(row)
del row
del cursor
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(floodplain, "CLEAR_SELECTION")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("ruleset4nonfc", "CLEAR_SELECTION")
fieldname = arcpy.ValidateFieldName("RS8_Floodplain")
arcpy.AddField_management("ruleset4nonfc", fieldname, "FLOAT")
cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("ruleset4nonfc", ["InFloodplain", "RS8_Floodplain"])
for row in cursor:
    if row[0] > 0:
        row[1] = 3
    else:
        row[1] = 1
    cursor.updateRow(row)
del row
del cursor
```

From what I can tell, these sections are functionally the same.  Can anyone explain why the interstates one does not work while these do?

Comment: Please include the full traceback

Comment: `row` is a tuple. You can't change a tuple. Easiest thing to do is convert it to a list, which is mutable, with `row = list(row)` right after your `for` statement.

Comment: Pardon, this is not an area of great familiarity for me.  How do I get a traceback?

Comment: traceback is the full error message that you get with the exception, it should include the exact module and line number which caused the error

Answer (score 0):

```
# Your Code
cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("ruleset4nonfc", ["ssGravity_Main_fullcctv_ASSET_ID", 
"WithinInterstates"])
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor ("ruleset4nonfc", ["ssGravity_Main_fullcctv_ASSET_ID", 
"WithinInterstates"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] > 0:
        row[1] = 5
        elif row[0] <= 0:
        row[1] = " "
        else:
        pass
del cursor
```

You create a update cursor but then you use a searchcursor instead? You cannot edit rows using a searchcursor. You simply need to use a searchCursor instead, as you did in the other examples.

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor ("ruleset4nonfc", ["ssGravity_Main_fullcctv_ASSET_ID", 
"WithinInterstates"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] > 0:
        row[1] = 5
        elif row[0] <= 0:
        row[1] = " "
        else:
        pass
```